A few questions about smooth paramter in lattice signature
I was recently studing lattice signature and reading the GPV08 paper.
For my comprehension, given a continuous guassian distribution, the smooth parameter decides a bound that, by placing the same distribution above on each lattice point, the probability of any position in the lattice space is uniform.
If the state above is correct, then my questions are:

How to construct a trapdoor sampling function (GPV08) from the properity of smooth paramter?
In hard random lattice (q-ary lattice), how the smooth parameter works?

